# Show that B is a closed subset of a metric space M

Tags: real-analysis

Let a be an element of a metric space $(M,\rho)$ and let $r>0$. Let $B=\{x \in M \mid \rho(a,x)=r\}$. Show that $B$ is a closed subset of $M$.

So on this problem I know that $\rho(a,x) =r$ with $r>0$ means that the distance between them cannot be zero. But how do I use that to show that $B$ is a closed subset of $M$?

Comment: By $\rho(a,x)$ you mean the distance between $a$ and $x$?

Comment: Yes I do! (M, rho) is an arbitrary metric space in this case

Comment: What definition(s) do you know for a set $A\subseteq M$ being closed in a metric space $\langle M,\rho\rangle?$

Comment: I have voted to put on hold for now. Until we know more (such as how "closed" is defined for you), we'll just be grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the compliment $M\setminus B_r(a)$ is open in $M$. That is, if $q$ is any point inside the circle of radius $r$ centered at $a$, then for any point $q$ inside the circle, you can find a small ball $B_{\epsilon}(q)$ around $q$ of radius $\epsilon$ that lies entirely inside the circle. Similarly, for $q'$ outside the circle, you can find a small ball $B_{\epsilon'}(q')$ around $q'$ of radius $\epsilon'$ such that lies entirely outside the circle. It's easy to convince yourself drawing a picture, but you should find appropriate $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$.

Comment: So if I show that the compliment is open, that implies that M is closed?

Comment: $B\subseteq M$ is open in $M\iff M\setminus B$ is closed in $M$. Note however, $B$ not closed DOES NOT mean that it is open. There are sets that are open, sets that are closed, sets that are both (clopen sets), and sets that are neither.

Comment: I'm not real certain of how to show that it is open though

Comment: An open set $X$ of a metric space is defined as follows: Open balls $B_r(a)=\{x:\rho(x,a)<r\}$ (think of disk in the plane without the circle bounding it) are open sets. take any $x\in X$. If you can draw some open ball $B_\epsilon(a)$ around $a$, and have the ball be entirely within $X$, and you can do this for every $x\in X$, then $X$ is open. In other words, for any $x\in X$, you can "wiggle" it a little bit in any direction and still stay within $X$. For a circle (which is what $B$ is in your example), that clearly is not the case. Another example, $[a,b)$ is not open because you can't

Comment: wiggle $a$ to the left and stay within $[a,b)$. However $(a,b)$ is open because you can wiggle any point  in $(a,b)$ and still be in $(a,b)$.

Comment: All the $ signs and all that are a bit confusing to follow

Answer (score 0):

Let $p\in M\setminus B.$ and let $\delta:=|r-\rho(a,p)|$ (note that $\delta\gt0$). Now let $x$ be an arbitrary point of the open ball $B_{\delta}(p)=B$ (with radius $\delta$ and center $p$). If $r\geqslant\rho(a,p)$ we have $$\begin{aligned}\rho(x,a)&\leqslant\rho(x,p)+\rho(p,a)\\\\&\lt\delta+\rho(p,a)\\\\&=|r-\rho(a,p)|+\rho(a,p)\\\\&=r\end{aligned}$$ and we are done. If $r\lt\rho(a,p)$ then we have $$\begin{aligned}\rho(a,p)&\leqslant\rho(a,x)+\rho(x,p)\\\\&\lt\rho(a,x)+\delta\\\\&=\rho(a,x)+|r-\rho(a,p)|\\\\&=\rho(a,x)+\rho(a,p)-r\end{aligned}$$ and so $r\lt\rho(a,x).$

Threfore any point of $M\setminus B$ is an interior point of $M\setminus B$ and hence it is open which means that $B$ is closed.